# How can I retrieve a HubContext (SignalR) inside a class with other constructor's parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, constructor, signalr

I have a class that have some parameters in the constructor.

```
public class ServerStatus
    {   
       private int idserver;
       private string des;
       private string ipserver;

       private int attemptfailded = 0;

        public ServerStatus(int id, string description, string ip)
        {
            this.idserver = id;
            this.des = description;
            this.ipserver = ip;    
        }

       ... /* Other logic of this class: like notification management */

    }
```

Now, I want to add in this class an instance of a hub context like this, and have a method that uses this hub context for example.

```
public class ServerStatus
{
   private readonly IHubContext<MyHub, ITypedHubClient> _hubContext;

   private int idserver;
   private string des;
   private string ipserver;

   private int attemptfailded = 0;

    public ServerStatus(IHubContext<MyHub, ITypedHubClient> hubContext, int id, string description, string ip)
    {
        this.idserver = id;
        this.des = description;
        this.ipserver = ip;
        _hubContext = hubContext;

    }

   ...

   public async Task SendMessageToClients()
   {       
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.BroadcastMessage("Server", 
        "ServerDown");
   }

}
```

In particular, I want that this class is instantiatable wherever I want, like, if I have another class that implements a list of this `ServerStatus` object, I need to call the constructor from this class. This is an example:

```
public static class MyClass
{

    public static List<ServerStatus> servers = new List<ServerStatus>();

    public static void initializeServers()
    {
        foreach (/* server I have in a Database */)
        {

            ServerStatus s = new ServerStatus (/* the hub context and the parameters of the server */)

            servers.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I add this `hubContext` to my class and instantiate the objects where I need them.

Remember, I have already set up all the SignalR library and this works, but now I don't understand how to pass the `hubContext` to a class that need it.

Comment: Use dependency injection tools! MEF for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your class need to be static?

When you register your classes/services in `ConfigureServices` they are registered to the .NET Core Service Provider. With non-static classes you can inject this interface and use it to request registered services from the .NET Core Service Provider e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

    public MyClass(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public void InitializeServers()
    {
        foreach(/* server I have in database */)
        {
            var hub = _provider.GetService<IHubContext<MyHub, ITypedHubClient>>();

            ServerStatus s = new ServerStatus(hub, ...);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the `IServiceProvider` to retrieve any services that have been registered with it, including your `IHubContext`.
Internally, .NET Core uses the service provider to inject services into your registered services/controllers etc. when it creates them. In this case you are just doing the same thing it does but manually.

NOTE:
You will need to register your `MyClass` in `startup.cs` for the service provider to be injected into the constructor. For example:

```
services.AddSingleton<MyClass>();
```

But, now you have registered `MyClass` with the service provider, you could just inject your dependency directly into `MyClass`

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub, ITypedHubClient> _hubContext;

    public MyClass(IHubContext<MyHub, ITypedHubClient> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public void InitializeServers()
    {
        foreach(/* server I have in database */)
        {
            ServerStatus s = new ServerStatus(_hubContext, ...);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to instantiate this class in your startup you can get hold of an instance in the `Configure` method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var myClass = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<MyClass>();

    myClass.InitializeServers();

    // the rest of the startup
    ...
}
```

`ApplicationServices` is an implementation of the `IServiceProvider` interface we mentioned earlier.

The call to `GetService` can go anywhere in the `Configure` method. It doesn't have to go right at the start.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Ok, I tried what you have answered to me, but I don't understand how to initialize my class now. Immagine that I want to instantiate  "My Class" from the ConfigureService, how can i do? Could you give me the example code?

Comment: You can do this from `Configure`. I've updated my answer to show how. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This work for me, nice and clean! I add to your answer a piece of code that you have omitted in order to work.